# All possible combinations of digits returned

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to a digit (i.e: 123), and return all the possible combinations of those 3 digits.

So for example:

123
132
213
231
321
312

Is there a function i can use for this in javascript?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/9960908/10221765

Comment: you are looking for *permutation*. maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441586/find-ith-permutation-in-javascript

Comment: I reckon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9960908/10221765) solves your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permutations in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript)